# Azure CLI 2.0 - GLIBC_2.17 not found

Tags: 14.04, command-line, azure

I am trying to construct a continuous integration pipeline using [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.com/). In this, I am trying to include the [Azure CLI 2.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli#apt-get) via `apt-get` on my CI box and am struggling to do so. I have the following `.travis.yml` config...

```
sudo: required

language: node_js

node_js:
- '7'

branches:
  only:
  - master

before_install:
- echo 'deb https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ wheezy main' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
- sudo apt-key adv --keyserver packages.microsoft.com --recv-keys 417A0893
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install azure-cli
- export PATH=$PATH:/azure-cli/bin
- echo $PATH
- az
```

With `$PATH` as such...

```
> /home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin /home/travis/bin
> /home/travis/.local/bin
> /home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.7.4.linux.amd64/bin
> /usr/local/phantomjs/bin 
> ./node_modules/.bin
> /usr/local/maven-3.2.5/bin
> /usr/local/clang-3.4/bin
> /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby2.2.6/bin
> /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6@global/bin
> /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.6/bin 
> /usr/local/sbin 
> /usr/local/bin
> /usr/sbin 
> /usr/bin 
> /sbin 
> /bin 
> /home/travis/.rvm/bin 
> /azure-cli/bin
```

When I `az`, I consistently get the following error with the following reason...

```
$ az
/opt/az/bin/python3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version
`GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /opt/az/bin/python3)
The command "az" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

I have been hunting down this `GLIBC_2.17` not found error to no avail. I am unsure what is going on here or why I can not install the Azure 2.0 CLI on my Travis box. Has anyone tried doing this or able to point out what I am overlooking here? Also, I have followed this exact steps on my local box and am good to go with using the CLI...

**Note** - while my question includes specifics to web development and commercial tooling, I keep finding myself coming to this community to further my understanding of Ubuntu. I hope my error is generic enough and can be tracked backed to OS specifics rather than the Travis-CI platform...

**Edit** - Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Please edit your above post to include Ubuntu version. Finding the object `GLIBC_2.17` :  `objdump -x /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep  GLIBC_2.1` ... I guess you are using Ubuntu 12.04? . All later supported versions have libc6-**2.19** or later.

Comment: Using 14.04 LTS - I believe the question is tagged with the version

Comment: OK, either your OS is 32bits ... or the application can't find libc in the special Ubuntu/Debian path´s = /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ , /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/